# How to display objects from local storage on to the website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

So I have created this website which lets users search for the weather in different cities. These searches then get saved in an object which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qi9f.png) through the localstorage.

To display this on the website I've tried to make the following

```
    <div class="jumbotron bg-white">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Latest requests</h1>
            <h5 id="get-weather">We remember your five last requests for you :)</h5>
            <div class="last-requests">
                <img src="" class="imgs">
                <p class="cityname" class="mr-3"></p>
                <p class="cityweather"></p>
                <p class="citytemp"></p>
                <p class="citywind"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the following JS

```
// Displays last 5 requests/searches
function displayLastRequests() {
  const lastReq = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last-requests'))
  console.log(lastReq)
  if (displayLastRequests > 0) {
    // for loop request
    for (req in lastReq) {
      $(".imgs").attr('src', req.imgurl);
      $(".cityname").text(req.city_name);
      $(".cityweather").text(req.city_weather);
      $(".citytemp").text(req.city_temp + " °C");
      $(".citywind").text(req.city_wind + " m/s");
    }
  }
};
displayLastRequests()
```

Not quite sure where I'm doing something wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `displayLastRequests()` inside a doc.ready or at the end of your code?  If it's at the start (eg in HEAD) then those elements won't exist when it runs.

Comment: Also, a selector like, `$(".imgs")` will select *all* elements with `class="imgs"` so only the last iteration of your `for (req...` will have any effect.

Comment: This also looks somewhat suspect:  `function displayLastRequests()...` `if (displayLastRequests > 0) {` - you're checking if your **function definition** is greater than 0?  Maybe you wanted `if(lastReq.length > 0` - but you don't need that as the `for` will only loop if there are entries.

Comment: @freedomn-m No there's a lot more code before this, just didn't want to post unnecessary code here. And as to the pictures I wasn't quite sure how to do it, I've noticed what you mentioned when I search for a new city that it tends to happen

Comment: The question wasn't "is this the only code" - the *location* of this code is relevant.  But yes, only including the relevant code is good.

Comment: To clarify: does the code that you've shown us work ok?   (for *one* saved search)?  You've not really described what the problem is in your question.

Comment: yes the code works for one search. https://gyazo.com/640dd9f1b5917daebf58c27127b38789 @freedomn-m

Comment: If the issue is that it works, but only 1 is displayed, not all 5 (edit:confirmed), then:  you need to clone the last-requests div for each entry.

Comment: If you can include a sample of the json in the question, we can get you a working solution quick enough.

Comment: This json? https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qi9f.png I've saved the attributes needed for the latest requests in an object. @freedomn-m

Comment: I was asking you to provide it as *code* in the question to save typing it out again, but went with a simulation instead of duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code will only show the last search as there's only one "cityname" to output to.

You can use HTML5 `<template>` to provide a ...well... template which you can copy and add as required.

Your `for` loop may also need to be `for (.. of ..)` rather than `.. in ..` which will give indexes rather than entries.

Updated code:

```js
function displayLastRequests() {
  //const lastReq = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last-requests'))
  // Sample data
  const lastReq = [
    {city_name:"Istanbul", weather:"Cloudy"},
    {city_name:"Madrid", weather:"Stormy"},
    {city_name:"London", weather:"Sunny"}
  ];
  console.log(lastReq)

  for (req of lastReq) {
    var clone = $($("#last-request-template").html());
    clone.appendTo(".last-requests");
    
    clone.find(".cityname").text(req.city_name);
    clone.find(".cityweather").text(req.weather);

    //clone.find(".imgs").attr('src', req.imgurl);
    //clone.find(".citytemp").text(req.city_temp + " °C");
    //clone.find(".citywind").text(req.city_wind + " m/s");    
  }
};
displayLastRequests()
```

```css
.last-requests { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
.last-request+.last-request { border-top: 1px solid #CCC; }
p { padding:5px; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron bg-white">
     <div class="container">
       <h1>Latest requests</h1>
       <h5 id="get-weather">We remember your five last requests for you </h5>
       <template id='last-request-template'>
         <div class='last-request'>
           <!--<img src="" class="imgs">-->
           <p class="cityname"></p>
           <p class="cityweather"></p>
           <!--<p class="citytemp"></p>-->
           <!--<p class="citywind"></p>-->
         </div>
       </template>
       <div class="last-requests"> </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of the HTML5 future where you could copy HTML templates and re-use where you please, thank you so much!

Comment: TBH a `<template>` is essentially just a `<div style='display:none;'>` :)  So in "old money" it would be to have a hidden div acting as a template that you copy for each new entry.

Comment: The only issue now is like you mentioned before, all images gets replaced with the new entry's image. Still not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: Make sure you do `clone.find(".imgs")` so that it only affects the one you're adding.  You can also do `$(".imgs", clone)` - it's the same, different syntax.